# Is there a finite group whose identities are the same as the group identities?

Tags: group-theory, universal-algebra

Consider the equational theory of groups in the signature $\{+,0,-\}$. The equational theory is axiomatized by the associative law, the identity laws, and the inverse laws. My question is, does there exist a finite group $G$ whose identities are precisely the same as the identities generated by the standard group identities? Note, I want $G$ to be finite.

Comment: Any finite group $G$, written additively,  must satisfies $nx=0$ for $n=|G|$. The group $(\mathbb Z; +,-,0)$ satisfies no such law.

Comment: **"My question is, does there exist a finite group G whose identities are precisely the same as the identities generated by the standard group identities? Note, I want G to be finite."** I do not understand what this question is asking. You should rephrase it, only using words to mean exactly one thing.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I am not convinced bringing up the group of integers is relevant.

Comment: @Angel The question is quite clear and uses only standard terminology of universal algebra. And Keith Kearnes has answered it correctly.

Comment: @KeithKearnes You should probably put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Angel The group of integers is quite relevant. I think you might not be interpreting the question properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any finite group $G$, written additively, must satisfy $nx=0$ for $n=|G|$. The group $(Z;+,−,0)$ satisfies no such law. Hence the group $(\mathbb Z; +, -, 0)$ does not belong to any variety of groups that is generated by a finite group.

Also, it is known from the work of Birkhoff that if $V = {\sf H}{\sf S}{\sf P}(A)$ is a variety generated by a finite algebra $A$ of size $k$, then any $n$-generated algebra in $V$ will have size at most $k^{k^n}$. Hence, the finitely generated members of any finitely generated variety will be finite. This yields a sufficient criterion to show that a variety is not generated by a finite algebra: if the variety contains a finitely generated infinite algebra, then the variety cannot be generated by a finite algebra. For this problem, you can apply this criterion to $(\mathbb Z; +, -, 0)$, since it is finitely generated and infinite.